# Is this number a palindrome?

Tags: number, integer, palindrome, fastest-algorithm

### Input

A single integer in your language's preferred format, e.g `int` or an array of digits are all acceptable.

### Output

A truthy or falsely value, depending on whether the given number is palindromic (same forwards and backwards)

### Rules

- Numbers will always be positive, at least two digits long.
- This is [fastest-algorithm](/questions/tagged/fastest-algorithm), so lowest O(n) time complexity wins.

## Test cases

- 123454321 - true
- 296296 - false
- 296692 - true
- 5499456 - false
- 0 - false/error/any value

Comment: In your rules you state the input is less than `99999999`, but the first test case is larger than this.

Comment: You state that the input is a 16-bit integer, but 4 of the 5 test cases don't fit on 16 bits.

Comment: Indeed, the upper bound, 99999999, doesn't fit in 16 bits.

Comment: Also: specifying any upper bound makes the problem trivially O(1). You should either change to fastest-code or remove the upper bound altogether.

Comment: OK, fixed all issues.

Comment: @GezaKerecsenyi No you didn't fix the issue of an upper bound making O(1) solutions trivial.

Comment: *in your language's preferred format* — What if my language's integer type is bounded? (E.g. 8, 16, or 32 bits.)

Comment: @Adám I assume you're referring to C & co., with long and long long being separate? Do it for the maximum your language supports. If that means hardcoding everything up to 32 bits, sure, but that will likely not be the winning entry. The same with the upper bound: it means it's _possible_ to hardcode everything, but that doesn't mean you should. Plus it makes the challenge pretty boring.

Comment: If boring solutions are the optimal solutions then that's a reflection of the challenge, not the solutions.

Comment: @GezaKerecsenyi if the "winning" entry is the one with the lowest O(n) score, then O(1) wins, which means that the only winning entry is the boring one...

Answer (score 6):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), *O*(1)

`⊃∘'111111111110`…  …`10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'`

Anonymous tacit prefix function.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7NqxTTNrFEXRcoiQPCVZQiKxBCkxCaIC6nMjJgMnRMafuZu1IqJ3NfO0zzj498@H@4eX/eHp8XQ6vr8e3z7utm@7L7/759l/@Xp/7RxxxJGf/jqvewHXXHPtJte8VNdcE7qX6pprQvdSXXNN6P4Xuuaa0F1zzTWhu@aaa0J3zTXXhO6aa64t@Xcybrjhxn9aGDfccEPxbrjhhuLdcMMNT@SGG254IjfccMNbc8MNN7w1N9xQvLfmhhuKd8MNN250w2tzww0fYDfccEPxbrjhhuLdcMMNxbvhhhuKd8MNNxTvhhtuKN4NN9zwRG644YYncsONxA2vzQ03fIDdcMMNxbvhhhuKd8MNNxTvhhtuKN4NN9xQvBtuuKF4N9xwwxO54YYbnsgNNxI3vDY33PABdsMNNxTvhhtuKN4NN9xQvBtuuKF4N9xwQ/FuuOGG4t1www1P5IYbbngiN9xI3PDa3HDDB9gNN9xQvBtuuKF4N9xwQ/FuuOGG4t1www3Fu@GGG4p3ww03PJEbbrjhidxwI3HDa3PDDR9gN9xwQ/FuuOGG4t1www3Fu@GGG4p3ww03FO@GG24o3g033PBEbrjhhidyw43EDa/NDTd8gN1www3Fu@GGG4p3ww03FO@GG24o3g033FC8G264oXg33HDDE7nhhhueyA03Eje8Njfc8AF2ww03FO@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@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@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@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@/y3a6P2/99/b5Pez2/WNYlLqs5WNY1M26rqdzU8ez61bjWerr71LLdJsu4@@uGz/1Hw)

Simply picks the result from a pre-compiled list.

Comment: Haha, nice. Didn't think about that. Well done! :)

Comment: @LuisMendo It works for me in FFQ/W10 but it takes a very long time to render. Let's hope OP doesn't go to 64 bits…

Comment: @Adám Ah, that was the issue here as well. It took about 1 minute (Chrome, W10)

Comment: The rules of the question have changed in a way that renders this answer invalid. (By no longer specifying a size of integer)

Comment: @pppery Also, the challenge is closed.

Answer (score 3):

## Java, complexity: \$O(\lfloor\log_{10}(n) + 1\rfloor)\$

```java
boolean f(int n){
  int reverse = 0;
  //int debugIterations = 0;
  for(int palindrome = n; palindrome != 0; palindrome /= 10){
    //debugIterations++;
    int lastDigit = palindrome % 10;
    reverse = reverse * 10 + lastDigit;
  }
  //System.out.println("Debug iterations: "+debugIterations);
  return n == reverse;
}
```

Loops once for every digit in the input-number. Pretty straight-forward implementation tbh..

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##bVFNa4QwFLz7K16Fgla6fqwuWPG2lx562mPpIa5RstVEkiiU4m@3SVZXkYYckpk3My8vNzSg11v5PV0bJAR8IEJ/LQAhkSRXmArGGowoVA6hEqirOX3ieMBcYMghyBTk@xoscdHX7xJzpWVULGTFuFF3qCG05KzVMppt70@6dAv4OYSBSdPmO2PPywyhTVXX8kxqIpXnRv@s5PeitdPl9KI48FalrhvNIy4/QuL2wHp56Lhyb6hjn3U2kEf4G9jerh9XO3Ase06BQv5IyqxxyizFdX3RqGnOQx0YKaFVg3YuUqXUn1@A5qdKLKQTRsc4iY9R6GYrGKUntXfIKY22SBKnaZwsRb5vwGBbkc5ri4X3nNFav910aMj11wH@mQ71bD2PyqHubDJOfw)

Answer (score 1):

## Java, O(1)

```java
boolean f(int n){
  if (n <= 0 || n >= 16777216) throw new Error(n+" is not a valid input!");
  int reverse = n/10000000%10*1 + n/1000000%10*10 + n/100000%10*100 + n/10000%10*1000 + n/1000%10*10000 + n/100%10*100000 + n/10%10*1000000 + n/1%10*10000000;
  int len = (int) Math.log10(n);
  reverse/= Math.pow(10, 7-len);
  return reverse == n;
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZJNc4IwGITv/oqtM52BWpVggKGW3nrsyWPbQ1TUWEyYEHA61d9OIx8i5pZnk519d949K9h4v/4pVwnLMnwwLvA3ADLNNF@VSymTmAlsLC40hH2R@AaWwGsEB6cTBN4iED8IApf4NvROySNEfMS7UlJZYjQEzyCkBkPBEr4GF2muH4b2/OJlXFVcxCqLEUFMiVOfR@I8EYw6UgHnhtTghjSgIy24kitoSQcacgOcNl4SCxPtMr9t6tG7SSK3xLFElb/JPo1qKZVHizjPCMbmV/NA50p0M5oh54NzCaT5MuGrpmcU0hRzMOVbC6242H5@g1VlAzrOtEXcmUsqwwa4oe/6dyB0e4BSrweI27cgLrnT7@SeSmnv1tM8GobU8/u/Z9Sjbejz4LpS9ajVm26lgMVvpuPDROZ6kpoCdCIuq/PypYejjem6cTmX/w)

Kevin Cruijssen's answer, unrolled for 24-bit numbers.

Comment: I can't post answers since this is on hold, so this is my answer: O(1)  ```a=input();print(1 if a[::-1]==a and len(a)>1 else 0)```

Comment: The rules of the question have changed in a way that renders this answer invalid. (By no longer specifying a size of integer)

Comment: @pppery It specifies "A single integer in your language's preferred format, e.g `int`", and I would consider my answer accepting an `int` to be as valid as it gets. It doesn't seem to disallow knowing the types size either.

Answer (score 0):

## APL+WIN, O(1)

Thanks to Adam for suggested changes to my original code and his explanation -  see the comments section.

Prompts for input of integer.

```
 17=+/(⌽17↑n)=¯17↑n←⍕⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcjzra0/4bmttq62s86tlraP6obWKepu2h9RAWUMmj3qlA1f@B6v6ncRkaGZuYmhgbGXKlcRlZmgERhGFmaQRkmJpYWpqYgoQMuLgA)

Comment: This isn't a `[code-golf]` challenge, it's `[fastest-algorithm]`.

Comment: @Kevin Cruijssen OK so how do we decide which algorithm is fastest. If you compare our examples on TIO APL looks faster?

Comment: If you compare the execution-speed it would be a `[fastest-code]` challenge. ;) I'm not very good at comparing complexity \$O\$ speeds tbh. But as the challenge is currently stated, the complexity is \$O(1)\$ anyway regardless of the implementation. The challenge is kinda pointless imho..

Comment: @Kevin Cruijssen OK if the op is not happy with my entry I will delete it. As APL is an interpreted language I have no idea what is going on under the hood so I do not know how it is handling the problem. I think given what you have said I agree it does seem pointless.

Comment: You should be able to guarantee O(1) with `17=+/(⌽17↑n)=¯17↑n←⍕⎕` since it always has to allocate more memory (3 bytes) than initially assigned (1 or 2 bytes), always reverses a length-17 string, always compares 17 character pairs, and always sums 17 Booleans.